# Junit do not find system scope dependency

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-plugin, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to create unit tests for a project that uses Maven. When I run my test, it throws this exception while trying to read a dependency named ENV.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
```

This is how this dependency looks like in my POM.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ENV</groupId>
    <artifactId>ENV</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${pathEnviroment}</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

JUnit does not behave this way with my other dependencies that are added to my local repository. So, I removed the scope and systemPath tags and added ENV to my local repository, but the test keeps throwing the same exception. Could someone please help me?

**Additional information that could help:**
I have a manifest file to make this dependency work in the .jar that I generate of the project.

Comment: Why having a dependency in system scope which deprecated a very long time ... also unit tests should be part of the project and made externally of the project... Also it would be helpful to have the full pom file and also the failing test including the code and some other information JDK, Maven Version etc...

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:

1. Check the `ENV` Dependency: Ensure that the `ENV` dependency is correctly installed in your local `Maven` repository. You mentioned that you added it to your local repository, so verify that it is installed properly.
2. Check the `systemPath:` If you are using the system scope for the `ENV` dependency, make sure that the systemPath specified in the POM.xml is correct and points to the location of the ENV JAR file on your system
3. Check the `NoClassDefFoundError`: The `NoClassDefFoundError` for `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` indicates that the `SLF4J` library is not being found at runtime. Ensure that the `SLF4J` library is included as a dependency in your project's POM.xml. You can add the `SLF4J` dependency.

---

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.32</version> <!-- Use the latest version -->
</dependency>
```

---

4. You mentioned that you have a manifest file to make the `ENV` dependency work in the generated JAR. Ensure that the manifest file is correctly configured to include the ENV dependency and its dependencies in the `Class-Path` attribute.
5. After making any changes to the `POM.xml`, run the Maven command to update the project and its dependencies:

---

```
`bash`
`mvn clean install`
```

---